# how do I add up the whole column in excel?

Tags: excel

how do I add up the whole column in excel if there are N/A values?

I cant seem to find a solution to enable me to omit the N/A values as it keeps returning an error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`AGGREGATE`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/aggregate-function-43b9278e-6aa7-4f17-92b6-e19993fa26df) which will ignore the errors:

```
=AGGREGATE(9,3,A:A)
```

Comment: Thanks Scott,it worked. never used aggregate before

Comment: Or, if you are using O365, then place this formula in Define Named Manager as  `=LAMBDA(x,AGGREGATE(9,3,x))` and named it as `MYSUM` , so you can use it in your spreadsheet as `MYSUM(x)` where `x=A:A`